# Compressing two children() calls into one

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors, children

How do I turn this, which uses two calls two `children`:

```
$('#id tr').children('td').children('input')
```

into something that calls children only once? I am trying to select every input text box inside a particular table row (`tr`) that's a child of `#id`. I've tried

```
$('#id tr').children('td input')
```

and

```
$('#id tr').children('td > input')
```

But neither of those work. I'm kinda new to these selector expressions, so sorry if it's obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I like the `$("#id tr td input")` suggestions, in some cases (e.g. if you had the `$("#id tr")` object from some other source) you might instead be looking for [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), which goes multiple levels deep (instead of `.children()` which only goes one):

```
$("#id tr").find("td input")
```

Comment: check my answer, which basically allows you to use the selector from another source.

Comment: @kuroir, yes, if you have the selector instead of the object, you can also use the `$("x", "y")` syntax. Although---not that it really matters---some testing I've seen shows `$("x", "y")` to be slower than `$("y").find("x")`. I find it worse because it's less explicit.

Comment: worked like a charm. The thing that's nice is that `find` goes multiple levels deep, which I didn't know till reading this answer, and because of that I can just reduce it to `$('#id').find('input');` Thanks again, +1 and check'd.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just `$('#id tr input')`?

Or maybe `$('#id input')`

Answer (score 1):

I'm amazed no one suggested this one:

```
$('td input', '#idc tr')
```

Which will allow you to have the `#idc tr` part from a variable. Basically what you're doing is doing a concatenation; so you read the right selector first, and then the left one, for instance:

```
$('> input', 'div')
```

Is the equivalent of:

```
$('div > input')
```

Now, lets do some golf here; the way you're passing the selector could be simplified to this two forms:

```
$('input', '#idc td')
// vs
$('#id').find('td input')
```

Both basically do the same, however as you may have noticed, the second one allows you to do jquery chaining; using `.end()` to go back to the previous selector `#id`.

I usually use the first statement whenever I need to do something simple that doesn't require me going back to the previous selector.

Answer (score -2):

U can set a class for your inputs and select it

`$('#id tr').children('td:input').hasclass('class name')`

Comment: This not only won't work because `td:input` is invalid syntax, it also won't work because `hasClass` (not `hasclass`) returns a boolean instead of a jQuery object.